# El fieldset se sale del formulario y hace que los inputs se salgan y no sea Responsive :(

Tags: html, css, formularios, margin

tengo el problema que como se aprecia en la foto, el fieldset se sale de los margenes del formulario, no se porque,  ya cheque el padding a modo de que solo el "formulario" tenga el padding y el margin pero no se soluciono :( , les dejo el codigo CSS y HTML, gracias de antemano.

```css
.formulario {
  background-color: #838383;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  width: min(60rem, 100%);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.formulario legend {
  color: var(--primario);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.formulario fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem 0.5rem 2rem;
}

.inputs-form {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.contenedor-campos {
  padding: 3rem;
}

.campo {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.campo label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: var(--blanco);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- .SECTION (FORM)-->
  <h2 class="apartado">Contacto</h2>
  <form class="formulario">
    <fieldset>
      <div>
        <legend>Contactanos llenando todos los campos</legend>
      </div>
      <div class="contenedor-campos">
        <div class="campo">
          <label>Nombre:</label>
          <input class="inputs-form" type="text" placeholder="Tu nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
          <label>Telefono:</label>
          <input class="inputs-form" type="tel" placeholder="Tu telefono">
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
          <label>Correo Electronico:</label>
          <input class="inputs-form" type="email" placeholder="Tu e-mail">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="campo">
        <label>Mensaje:</label>
        <textarea name="name" rows="5" cols="80"></textarea>
        <input class="inputs-form" type="submit" value="Enviar">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Porque le pones esto?  `width: min(60rem, 100%);`  Eso hace que el formulario tenga ese mínimo y se salga de madre. Quítalo a ver si con eso es suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Al fieldset ponle un max-width, considero que sea del 100%. Eso hará qué no sea más grande que su contenrdor

Comment: Si, ya lo intente pero debería funcionar sin el max-width :(

Answer (score 0):

Le estas dando un tamaño fijo al formulario de 60 rem = 960px, quitalo o dejalo en 100% y si la raíz no tiene tamaño (body sin width o container principal sin width) puedes usar 100vw para que tenga el tamaño del viewport (pantalla)